# Unix & Linux Files Concurrent Read/Write Handling

Tags: linux, apache, unix, content-management-system

Some information first.

Web server document root: `/mySite/docroot/`

```
CMS writes a **new** file index-new.html to a SAN/NAS filesystem (Linux/Unix): /mySite/docroot/

CMS writes to an **existing** file index-ex.html to a SAN/NAS filesystem (Linux/Unix): /mySite/docroot/
```

Browsers access web server which reads `index-new.html` & `index.ex.html` under `/mySite/docroot/`

Here comes the questions.

What is the behaviour when CMS is writing index-new.html & index-ex.html (50% done only) while web server reads them at the same time?

Are the files automatically locked by Linux/Unix during file write to avoid other processes from reading and writing?

If yes, will the web server wait until the lock is released or just returns the error if the lock is detected?

If no, how to ensure the web server sends files with integrity addressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. File writes are not atomic.

The basic idea here is to create a temporary file and rename it. Renaming a file is atomic, so there would be either a "not exist" error or correct hit.

Additionally, when overwriting an existing file, the `rename()` call on Linux or equavilent calls for other OS will atomically overwrite the file. In this way, you can ensure that either the old one or new one is served, both in complete form.

Comment: Does this imply there is no way to ensure the file is always available to clients by forcing them to wait? Because there must be a short time that the old file is deleted during rename and they receive 404 error?

Comment: If there's an existing file and a new file is renamed to replace it, there will be no visible downtime (atomicity provided by kernel).

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if your problem is solved.